# htaccess 301 redirect: Matching subfolder to array

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

We are looking to redirect some query pages that are dynamically created based on a user search query, to subject pages (only if the query exactly matches a subject that we have in a list. This list contains +1000 subjects.).

Example:

$subjects = array("Marketing", "History", "Management", "Chemistry");

https://example.com/courses/?search=marketing should redirect to https://example.com/courses/subjects/marketing/ given that it exists in our array of subjects.

https://example.com/courses/?search=email+marketing should not redirect, given that it does not exist in our subjects array.

We are looking to perform these redirects on the server side using the htaccess  file. Any suggestions on how to best execute on this?

Comment: If you want to do this in `.htaccess` then I suggest using `RewriteMap` (will require you to make one line change in Apache server config)

Comment: Hi @anubhava,thank you for your comment. I am incredibly unfamiliar with RewriteMap. As I understand correctly, it allows you to call in an external script to execute the rewriting of the url? What code has to be used in this external script? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure. I have an external hosting server. Might be able to make changes via cPanel or by contacting the provider?

Comment: In that case you won't be able to use `RewriteMap`. You will have to do this from php code

Comment: You mean on the pages themselves? I've heard its bad SEO practice to redirect from page instead of server but if it's the only option, that's what we'll have to do.